# Reindex elasticsearch from remote host

Tags: elasticsearch, migration, reindex

I am migrating from an older elasticsearch to newer one. To copy indices from older cluster, I am using the `_reindex` api provided by elastic search. Now the problem is, my previous clustr is behind a proxy wall and I am getting 401 unauthorised. The proxy used cookies for authentication, so is there any way to send cookie in request for reindex?

I checked the docs for the api but it didnt contain anything about cookies - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html